# Repeat 1,2,3,4,5 in a row using column() in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is there a way to loop numbers 1-5 using column() or row() when dragging right?
For example F1=1,G1=2,H1=3,I1=4,J1=5, and then K1=1,L1=2....
so and so forth?

I tried column()-floor((column()/5),1), but once it hits J1, the answer is 0, not 4.

Answer (score 1):

Put this in F1:

```
=MOD(COLUMN(A:A)-1,5)+1
```

And copy across.

`5` is the repetition range and `+1` the start number.

[image]

Comment: Omg that works - that seems so simple! Not sure why it works though!